# What are the spots on my chili plant?

Tags: plant-health, vegetables, plant-care, chili

this is my first vegetable plant and I have no idea what to do or if this is something normal. My plant has white spots on older leaves and they turn brown over time. Anyone here who has seen this before and knows what I can do about it?

Cheers :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On the second photo, the bullseye pattern on the lower right is definately fungal disease. While you research what to do, keep the leaves dry